# If statements and admin privileges in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, privileges

I am building a user account system in CodeIgniter, and am having tremendous trouble using session data to lock or unlock links.  The following code is based on advice from Stack Overflow ([Controlling User Privileges in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10251931/controlling-user-privileges-in-codeigniter)):

```
<div id="navbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Bodycontroller">Chapters</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <?php if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')) : ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Users/login">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Users/register">Register</a></li>
          <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if($this->session->userdata('user_class') == 1) : ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Users">User List</a></li>
          <? endif; ?>
          <?php if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) : ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Bodycontroller/create">Compose</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Users/logout">Logout</a></li>
          <?php endif; ?>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

The Compose and Logout links work, but the User List link does not.  It fails to display regardless of which user is logged in.  I have already verified that the session cookie contains the correct user class.

I am presuming that this is a syntax problem, but the Codeigniter manual has no information on IF statements in this situation.  The specific code from Stack Overflow is paraphrased as follows:

```
      <?php if($this->session->userdata('user_class') == 1) : ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Users">User List</a></li>
      <? endif; ?>
```

My sense is that the absolute equality operator "== 1" may be in an incorrect form, despite it being copied from Stack Overflow.

One more thing:  It is NOT a boolean.  Some of the earlier respondents misunderstood my original question.  1 is a user class, as opposed to 2 or 3.  Therefore, I've tried making it a varchar or text datatype as well as an int, with no luck.

In short, does it need any kind of brackets or quotes (I've tried everything I know already)?  The CodeIgniter manual is unclear on this.  Any assistance in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `var_dump($this->session->userdata('user_class'));` I'm assuming it is a string so you would have to cast it as a int or assign it correctly when you assign it e.g. not using quotes. or when you check it use `=="1"`. using userdata as you are is the correct way of doing things in CI but your comparison depends on the var type.

Comment: I shouldn't have said "assignment."  I was typing in a hurry.  I meant the opposite, in other words how I indicate that the user_class field in the session cookie must be set to 1 in order for the list to appear.  The user_class is an int, both on the CodeIgniter page and in the original database.

Comment: well the first step is to var_dump it. does it exist? what is it? can you provide me with that information so I can help you debug this further?

Comment: Using the equality operator `1 == '1'` is true, but using the identical operator `1 === '1'` is false. So you do not have a syntax problem.

Comment: A helpful hint: You can use the URI string as an argument to `base_url()` e.g. `<a href="<?php echo base_url('Users/logout'); ?>">Logout</a>` It is usually easier to read and makes better use of `base_url`

Comment: @DFriend indeed forgot about the difference between `==` and `===`. hence why i seem to be leaning towards the variable not getting set properly, but op doesn't seem to be responding.

Comment: You are right, it is not set correctly. It is certainly not `1` or `"1"` or even `true`.

Comment: Some clarification is necessary here.  "1" is a user class in the database, as opposed to "2".  It is not a boolean.  It could just as easily be "admin," with a varchar or text datatype, but I was trying to simplify the code to use int.  Is this part of my problem?  Getting back to my original question, though, how do I write an IF statement to check the value of a field in a session cookie?  What is the syntax?

Comment: Your code should work. You use an acceptable way to check the value of session data. The equality operator - `==`  - will automatically juggle the type so you can compare an int to a string. As i stated earlier `1=="1"` is `TRUE`. Your description tends to indicate that the value of `$_SESSION['user_class']` is either not set or is not equal to (int) 1 or (string) "1".

Comment: Quetion: What version of CodeIgniter are you using?

Comment: I'm using CodeIgniter version 3.1.9, and I have checked the value of the session.  It appears to be correct.  I might have to try a string like "admin" to see what happens, but I'm getting close to a deadline.  If anyone has any further advice I would be very grateful.

Comment: Update:  I have attempted to use 'admin' instead of '1' for the user class, and again nothing happens.  The link that is supposed to be available to admins doesn't appear when an admin is logged in.  

The code is as follows:      

 <?php if($this->session->userdata('user_class') == 'admin') : ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Users">User List</a></li>
          <? endif; ?>

Comment: I have also tried without quotes:

 <?php if($this->session->userdata('user_class') == admin) : ?>

Then this error:

Use of undefined constant admin - assumed 'admin' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

Filename: templates/header.php

Line Number: 24

Backtrace:

File: C:\MAMP\htdocs\contentmanager\application\views\templates\header.php
Line: 24
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\MAMP\htdocs\contentmanager\application\controllers\Bodycontroller.php
Line: 19
Function: view

File: C:\MAMP\htdocs\contentmanager\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once